# Basic sorting in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, unit-testing

Previously asked [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123261/implementing-basic-sorting-in-python).

I would like to get my code for implementation of simple sorting algorithms in idiomatic python code reviewed. I am looking for feedback on python idioms used, better ways of doing the same thing. I am familiar with FP, and I am willing to put in effort to get myself familiar with pythonic idioms such as list comprehensions and enumerators. Hence I would also like feedback on if any of the explicit loops can be converted to these.

```
import doctest
from hypothesis import given
import hypothesis.strategies as st
```

#### Insertion Sort

```
def insertionsort(items):
    """
    >>> insertionsort([])
    []
    >>> insertionsort([1])
    [1]
    >>> insertionsort([1,2,3,4,5])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    >>> insertionsort([4,5,3,1,2])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    """
    for k, v in enumerate(items):
        for i, val in enumerate(items[:k]):
            if v < val:
                items[i], items[i + 1:k + 1] = items[k], items[i:k]
                break
    return items


@given(st.lists(elements=st.integers()))
def test_insertionsort(x):
    assert insertionsort(x) == sorted(x)
```

#### Selection Sort

```
def selectionsort(items):
    """
    >>> selectionsort([])
    []
    >>> selectionsort([1])
    [1]
    >>> selectionsort([1, 0])
    [0, 1]
    >>> selectionsort([2, 1, 0])
    [0, 1, 2]
    >>> selectionsort([1,2,3,4,5])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    >>> selectionsort([4,5,3,1,2])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    """
    for k in reversed(range(1, len(items))):
        v, i = max((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(items[:k]))
        if items[k] < v:
            items[k], items[i] = items[i], items[k]
    return items


@given(st.lists(elements=st.integers()))
def test_selectionsort(x):
    assert selectionsort(x) == sorted(x)
```

#### Bubble Sort

```
def bubblesort(items):
    """
    >>> bubblesort([])
    []
    >>> bubblesort([1])
    [1]
    >>> bubblesort([1, 0])
    [0, 1]
    >>> bubblesort([2, 1, 0])
    [0, 1, 2]
    >>> bubblesort([1,2,3,4,5])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    >>> bubblesort([4,5,3,1,2])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    """
    for i in range(len(items)):
        mod = False
        for j in range(len(items) - 1):
            if items[j + 1] < items[j]:
                mod = True
                items[j + 1], items[j] = items[j], items[j + 1]
        if not mod: break
    return items


@given(st.lists(elements=st.integers()))
def test_bubblesort(x):
    assert bubblesort(x) == sorted(x)
```

#### Heap Sort

```
def siftup(items, i):
    while i > 0:
        p = (i - 1) // 2
        if items[p] < items[i]:
            items[p], items[i] = items[i], items[p]
        i = p
    return items


def siftdown(items, last):
    p = 0
    while p <= last:
        l = 2 * p + 1
        r = l + 1
        max = p
        if l <= last and items[max] <= items[l]: max = l
        if r <= last and items[max] <= items[r]: max = r
        if max == p: break
        items[p], items[max] = items[max], items[p]
        p = max
    return items


def heapsort(items):
    """
    >>> heapsort([])
    []
    >>> heapsort([1])
    [1]
    >>> heapsort([1,2,3,4,5])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    >>> heapsort([4,5,3,1,2])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    """
    for i, t in enumerate(items):
        items = siftup(items, i)
    for i in reversed(range(len(items) - 1)):
        items[i + 1], items[0] = items[0], items[i + 1]
        items = siftdown(items, i)
    return items


@given(st.lists(elements=st.integers()))
def test_heapsort(x):
    assert heapsort(x) == sorted(x)
```

#### Merge Sort

```
def merge(left, right):
    """
    >>> merge([2,4,6], [])
    [2, 4, 6]
    >>> merge([], [2,4,6])
    [2, 4, 6]
    >>> merge([1,3,6], [2,4,6])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6]
    """
    if not left:
        return right
    elif not right:
        return left
    elif left[0] < right[0]:
        return left[:1] + merge(left[1:], right)
    else:
        return right[:1] + merge(left, right[1:])


def mergesort(items):
    """
    >>> mergesort([])
    []
    >>> mergesort([1])
    [1]
    >>> mergesort([1,2,3,4,5])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    >>> mergesort([4,5,3,1,2])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    """
    if len(items) <= 1: return items
    mid = len(items) // 2
    left = mergesort(items[:mid])
    right = mergesort(items[mid:])
    return merge(left, right)


@given(st.lists(elements=st.integers()))
def test_mergesort(x):
    assert mergesort(x) == sorted(x)
```

#### Quick Sort

```
def partition(items, begin, end, pivot):
    f = begin + 1
    l = end
    while True:
        while f <= l and items[f] <= pivot: f += 1
        while f <= l and items[l] >= pivot: l -= 1
        if f < l:
            items[l], items[f] = items[f], items[l]
        else:
            break
    items[l], items[begin] = items[begin], items[l]
    return l


def qsort(items, fst, lst):
    if fst >= lst: return
    pivot = items[fst]
    l = partition(items, fst, lst, pivot)
    qsort(items, fst, l - 1)
    qsort(items, l + 1, lst)


def quicksort(items):
    """
    >>> quicksort([])
    []
    >>> quicksort([1])
    [1]
    >>> quicksort([1,2,3,4,5])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    >>> quicksort([4,5,3,1,2])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    >>> quicksort([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    """
    if not items: return items
    qsort(items, 0, len(items) - 1)
    return items


@given(st.lists(elements=st.integers()))
def test_quicksort(x):
    assert quicksort(x) == sorted(x)
```

#### Shell Sort

```
def sort_gap(items, start, gap):
    for k in range(len(items) - 1, 0, -1 * gap):
        v, i = max((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(items[:k:gap]))
        if items[k] < v:
            items[k], items[i] = items[i], items[k]


def shellsort(items):
    """
    >>> shellsort([])
    []
    >>> shellsort([1])
    [1]
    >>> shellsort([1,2,3,4,5])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    >>> shellsort([4,5,3,1,2])
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    """

    gap = len(items) // 2
    while gap > 0:
        for i in range(gap):
            sort_gap(items, i, gap)
        gap = gap // 2
    return items


@given(st.lists(elements=st.integers()))
def test_shellsort(x):
    assert shellsort(x) == sorted(x)
```

#### Hypothesis Tests

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_selectionsort()
    test_bubblesort()
    test_insertionsort()
    test_quicksort()
    test_mergesort()
    test_heapsort()
    test_shellsort()
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks nice and well tested: congratulations. I have  a few comments anyway.

**A little design/API comment**

Compare [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted):

> sorted(iterable[, key][, reverse])
>
> **Return a new** sorted list from the items in iterable.

and [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

> sort(*, key=None, reverse=None)
>
> This method sorts the list **in place**[...] it **does not return** the sorted sequence.

The difference is that one operates in place and the other one returns a new list. Your code does both which is likely to be confusing.

**Other various comments**

You could (and probably should) pass the sorting function as a parameter to your testing function. You'd have something like :

```
@given(st.lists(elements=st.integers()))
def test_sort(x, my_sorted):
    assert my_sorted(x) == sorted(x)
```

and :

```
for s in [selection, bubble, insertion, quicksort, mergesort, heapsort, shellsort]:
    test_sort(s)
```

---

The variable name `mod` might a bit confusing as one might think about the modulo operator. I guess `modif` or `change` would be better.

**Suggestion**

It might be worth defining a `swap(i, j)` function/method but it might affect performances.